# For .NET Framework, which is the best expression evaluation engine you have used?

Tags: c#, .net

Need to use an expression evaluation engine for a .NET project.  So far I have found these two:

FLEE - http://flee.codeplex.com/
NCALC - http://www.codeplex.com/ncalc

Wondering if any of you have used one of these or perhaps a new one I not aware of. Please, share your experience.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 3):

[Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html) has a nice expression evaluator that I continue to use.  I don't have much to compare it against though.

A summary (from their docs):

> The Spring.Expressions namespace
>   provides a powerful expression
>   language for querying and manipulating
>   an object graph at runtime. The
>   language supports setting and getting
>   of property values, property
>   assignment, method invocation,
>   accessing the context of arrays,
>   collections and indexers, logical and
>   arithmetic operators, named variables,
>   and retrieval of objects by name from
>   Spring's IoC container. It also
>   supports list projection and
>   selection, as well as common list
>   aggregators.

Comment: any full sample that you use it ?